# Is it ok to say "would have had to have played" and "to have even had"?

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives, perfect-aspect

Are the bold parts grammatically correct? It sounds to me like the tenses are a bit redundant.

> In the second round, Djokovic faced Bobby Reynolds, a journeyman American making his Centre Court début at the age of thirty. Reynolds told me later, “I **would have had to have** played an unbelievable match, and he would have had to have played C-level, for me to **have even had** a chance.”

Comment: @kih1930, I'm not great at explaining the "why"s behind these types of questions, but the idea is that this is a counterfactual and it's in the past. So *would have* means *there must have been a world where things were different and this happened* and *had to have played* means that this counterfactual scenario is in the past, and the playing must have been [x]. I have no idea if that makes any sense, but I tried! I'm sure someone else will come along with a better answer.

Comment: Dear god, this sentence is simultaneously gruesome and fascinating, like a unicorn roadkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, they're grammatically correct.

**No**, they aren't redundant.  The "extra" ***have***s are not "extra" at all; they're used to put the verbs into the present perfect.  I'll try to explain each verb one at a time:

---

First, let's break down the first clause:

> *I would **have**<sup>1</sup> **had**<sup>2</sup> to **have**<sup>3</sup> **played**<sup>4</sup> an unbelievable match*

***have**<sup>1</sup>* and ***have**<sup>3</sup>* are both auxiliary verbs.  In each case, they combine with the past participle of the following main verb (***had**<sup>2</sup>* and ***played**<sup>4</sup>*, respectively) to form a present perfect construction.

***had**<sup>2</sup>*, on the other hand, is a main verb, just like ***played**<sup>4</sup>*.  Followed by ***to***, it expresses ["must; need to; to be required to"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_to).  This expresses a logical requirement of the final clause (*for me to have even had a chance*).

The meaning is essentially the same as the present version:

> *I would **have**<sup>2</sup> to **play**<sup>4</sup> an unbelievable match*

The only difference is that the main verbs (2 and 4) have been replaced with present perfect versions (1+2, and 3+4), so it's no longer in the present.

---

We can say the same thing about the final clause:

> *for me to **have**<sup>5</sup> even **had**<sup>6</sup> a chance.*

Again, ***have**<sup>5</sup>* is an auxiliary verb that combines with the past participle of the following main verb, ***had**<sup>6</sup>*, forming the present perfect construction ***have**<sup>5</sup>* ***had**<sup>6</sup>*.  The main verb, ***had**<sup>6</sup>*, in this case expresses *possession*.

Again, we can compare this to the present version:

> *for me to even **have**<sup>6</sup> a chance.*

This has the same meaning, except that it's in the present tense.

---

Let's take a look at what the full quote would look like in the present tense:

> *I would **have**<sup>2</sup> to **play**<sup>4</sup> an unbelievable match, and he would **have** to **play** C-level, for me to even **have**<sup>6</sup> a chance.*

As you can see, all three ***have***s are main verbs expressing meaning.  We obtain all the other ***have***s by transforming each verb into a present perfect construction (***have had*** or ***have played***).